# Different between Eventbus and Google Pub/SUb

Tags: typescript, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, event-bus

FYI, I know this question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340892/the-difference-between-a-message-queue-eventbus-and-a-pub-sub).

But I have a bit specific question.

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Can I use `EventBus` with `Google` `Pub/Sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What is different between them ?**

As we can see on [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) of Guava EventBus, it's used on the distribution of java events inside an application.

> It is designed exclusively to replace traditional Java in-process event distribution using explicit registration. **It is not a general-purpose publish-subscribe** system...

Cloud Pub/Sub **is** a a general-purpose publish-subscribe with a large variety of [use cases](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#common_use_cases).

Documentation says:

> This supports an "enterprise event bus" and event-driven application design patterns.

but it's different from what Guava's does.

**2. Can I use Eventbus with Google Pub/Sub ?**

Thinking of developing, I may say you can use Pub/Sub for your App intra-communication. But it's going to be different from what Guavas do and work.