# Is this a message bus based pub-sub pattern?

Tags: go, design-patterns, publish-subscribe

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969224/3317808),

> A Message Bus is a messaging infrastructure to allow different systems to communicate through a shared set of interfaces(message bus).

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PkJy.gif]

---

Below is the `createHub()` function & `Run()` method launched by `main()` to create message hub to communicate a publisher with multiple subscribers:

```
type PubHub struct {
    subscribers map[*subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription]struct{}
    Register    chan *subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription
    Unregister  chan *subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription
    Broadcast   chan *events.Env
}


func createHub() *PubHub {

    return &PubHub{
        subscribers: map[*subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription]struct{}{},
        Register:    make(chan *subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription),
        Unregister:  make(chan *subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription),
        Broadcast:   make(chan *events.Envelope),
    }
}

func (h *PubHub) Run() {

    for {
        select {
        case subscriber := <-h.Register:
            h.subscribers[subscriber] = struct{}{}

        case subscriber := <-h.Unregister:
            if _, ok := h.subscribers[subscriber]; ok {
                delete(h.subscribers, subscriber)
            }
        case message := <-h.Broadcast:
            for subscriber := range h.subscribers {
                subscriber.DataChannel <- message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

where each subscriber registers, as shown below:

```
    subscription := &subscriptionmediator.HandlerSubscription{
        conn,
        make(chan *events.Envelope),
    }
    hub.Register <- subscription
```

---

`DataChannel` is used for communication between publisher & multiple subscribers

```
type HandlerSubscription struct {
    ConnInstance *websocket.Conn
    DataChannel  chan *events.Envelope
}
```

---

1) Can the above code be considered following message bus based pub-sub pattern?

2) How to avoid one subscriber blocking rest all subscribers, from signalling on a channel? `subscriber.DataChannel <- message`

Comment: Regardless how to call it: `subscriber.DataChannel <- message` this is blocking, which means one slow or (worse) stuck subscriber would block the world.

Comment: @CeriseLimón So, does `select` syntax verify, if client is blocked, by sending message (`client.send <- message`)? If no success, then run the `default` case and close the channel...

Comment: @CeriseLimón Can `PubHub` be considered as an implementation of  message hub mentioned [here](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageBus.html)?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69641809/how-to-handle-connection-drop-from-source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the above code be considered following message bus based pub-sub pattern?

Yes.

Comment: But message bus should not be blocking one subscriber...due to another subscriber running slow, as mentioned in the comment

Comment: @overexchange, perhaps you should have included the definition of message bus you want to use in the question. And if you do that the answer may become obvious.

Comment: @overexchange "following [... a] pattern" is not the same as "is this a clever, suitable and production implementation of...".

Comment: @Peter Do you mean the `DataChannel`? I have added in the query...